# Activity that runs when only first using

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make a activity which runs when the only first using.
If user sets up the specific option at the activity screen, then the activity doesn't run anymore.
I want to make the user see the original activity screen at the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to handle this.

When your application launches first time and user sets specific options , you can set the value as:

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("isFirstLaunchFinished", true).commit().

for next time onwards you can check :

boolean isLaunched= sharedPref.getBoolean("isFirstLaunchFinished", defaultValue);

if(isLaunched){

//then you can start new activity and finish() previous one here

}

Answer (score 1):

Probably I think that one of the possible variants is to use `Preferences`. You just put a boolean flag (or something like this), which indicates if user already visited this activity. Maybe not very understandable answer, but you are welcome to ask

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences#java for best practices regarding key/value data persistence. To give a very basic example on how to do this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sharedPref.edit().putBoolean("KeyGoesHere", true).commit() // better to use apply though!
boolean hasSeenFirstPage = sharedPref.getBoolean("KeyGoesHere", defaultValue);
```